# Collection cannot be null exception when using HashSet in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following in my NHibernate entity:

```
    private ICollection<string> _stringSet = new HashSet<string>();
    public virtual ICollection<string> StringSet
    {
        get { return _stringSet; }
    }
```

Then, in my Fluent mapping I map it like so:

```
    HasMany(x => x.StringSet)
        .Table("String_Set")
        .Element("StringValue")
        .AsSet();
```

Unfortunately, when I try to save the entity, I get an `ArgumentNullException` saying the "Collection cannot be null." I do not get this error if I default my field to a List, but as you see in my mapping, I want Set behavior, even from an unsaved entity. It appears to me to be a problem with `HashSet<>` not implementing the non-generic `ICollection`. What is the proper way to have Set behavior for unsaved entities? I would also prefer to retain the `ICollection<string>` as my exposed type.

Comment: can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Aha. I thought I had stripped away all the Fluent conventions, but apparently there was a collection convention setting it to .AsBag(). Works as expected once the convention was removed, although it seems like a bug (or at least unexpected behavior) that the .AsSet() was not overriding the .AsBag() convention.

Comment: feel free to answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough rep to answer my own question, sadly.

Comment: You just need to wait 8 hours before you can answer your own question with rep less than 100.

Comment: And now I can't mark the answer in for another 22 :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha. I thought I had stripped away all the Fluent conventions, but apparently there was a collection convention setting it to .AsBag(). Works as expected once the convention was removed, although it seems like a bug (or at least unexpected behavior) that the .AsSet() was not overriding the .AsBag() convention.